# Será possível pela latitude e longitude saber se a direção?

Tags: php, javascript

Galera já peço perdão se a pergunta não estiver sentido !

Sera possível pela coordenada latitude, longitude saber a direção do veiculo exemplo se ele esta ao norte ou ao sul  ou leste ou oeste exemplo com o php ou javascript  !

Comment: Norte, sul, leste ou oeste em relação a o quê? Ilha null?

Comment: Quiz dizer pela coordenada exemplo  -4.3141, -69.5711 se colocar essa coordenada no Google Maps ele vai esta no rio amazonas mais preciso sabe se ele esta subindo o rio ou descendo o rio

Comment: Você quer saber movimento?

Comment: Você precisa de no mínimo dois pontos obtidos em momentos diferentes para saber em que direção está indo.

Comment: oi @Renan tenho as duas coordenada sim vou recebo a cada 5 minutos cada coordenada

Comment: Tenho a latitude e longitude a cada 5 minutos ai o seguinte tem o ponto A  e ponto B mais entre os  ponto recebo a cada 5 minutos a coordenada mais preciso saber se ele esta indo para o ponto A ou indo para o Ponto B

Comment: Cara é uma duvida válida, mas da uma lida melhor sobre coordenadas geográficas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O que você deseja é uma mistura de GPS com [navegação inercial](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inertial_navigation_system). Alguns aplicativos como o Maps do Google e o Waze fazem isso para saber a direção que um veículo segue, especialmente em dispositivos sem bússola.

A técnica é simples: obtenha as coordenadas do dispositivo em dois pontos distintos. A direção que o dispositivo segue é o vetor que liga os dois pontos e parte do primeiro obtido.

A dificuldade é que esse vetor deve ser obtido em três dimensões, com cálculo geodésico. Deixo ao seu critério pesquisar a matemática envolvida, bem como a determimação das API's a serem utilizadas. Javascript pode ser utilizado para obter dados de geolocalização no navegador. Não sei se PHP tem API nativa para isso, mas creio que há bibliotecas para se trabalhar com GPS.

E se tiver uma dúvida mais específica, não hesite em abrir uma nova pergunta.

Comment: Bem legal a resposta.